# SendGrid email failure

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

I am facing the below error when sending an email using SendGrid API.

[image]

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Exception page, I can tell your Laravel version is >=7, from laravel 7 onwards, the correct env variable is `MAIL_MAILER` and not `MAIL_DRIVER` so changing this in your .env file should solve the issue.